# How can I recurse in JS to repeat a string n times?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to make the code below repeat string `s` `n` number of times, however, it will always repeat `n - 1` times, because I need to pass a decrement to exit the recursion or I will exceed the max call stack.

```
function repeatStr (n, s) {
  while(n > 1) {
   result = repeatStr(-n, s)
    return s = s.concat(s)
  }
}
repeatStr(3, "Hi")
```

What can I change to make it recurse correctly?

Comment: The `return` inside your loop will terminate the function immediately.

Comment: `"Hi".repeat(3)` is already built-in

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work with str.repeat. I would also like to know a recursion way of doing this.

Comment: You cannot have that while loop, it defeats the point of applying recursion as a solution. It needs to be an if conditional that decides in continuing or completion of the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion involves making a function call itself and AVOIDS using a loop. You have a loop in the recursive function which is a big red flag.

Do something like this:
If n is 1 return s else return s concatenated to the result of the function with n - 1.

```
function repeatStr (n, s) {
   if (n == 1) 
       return s;
   else
       return s.concat(repeatStr(n - 1, s))
}
repeatStr(3, "Hi")
```

Comment: You don't need the `else`.   If it returns from the first `if` ...

Comment: No you don't, but it matches my explanation exactly so is less confusing for someone new.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for n <= 0, it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm demonstrating some basic logic here, not trying to cover the edge cases. Best to help understand the core issue here first.

Comment: But rather than thinking about that as an edge case, it might be worth showing the simple logic that fixes that problem, because it's useful over a large range of recursion problems.  (That is, of course, replacing `n == 1` with `n <= 1`.)  This might lead to an investigation of whether `1` or `0` is the appropriate base case, and simply be more instructive.  Of course Stephen Quan's answer may have already cornered the market on instructive answers!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're new to programming and JavaScript, let's work up to the solution. Start with a simple case, e.g. `repeatStr(3, "Hi")`. One simple answer may be:

```
function repeatStr(n, s) {
    return "HiHiHi";
}
```

Here, we assume what the inputs are always 3 and "Hi". We don't have a while loop, and we don't have recursion. We have the correct answer for those specific inputs but no other inputs are supported.

Let's make the answer a little bit harder:

```
function repeatStr(n, s) {
    return "Hi" + "Hi" + "Hi";
}
```

Here, again, we are assuming the inputs are 3 and "Hi". We still don't have a while loop nor do we have recursion.

Okay, let's start using one of your inputs:

```
function repeatStr(n, s) {
    return s + s + s;
}
```

Here, we are finally using the string that's passed in as `s`. We can handle inputs other than `"Hi"` to generate a correct answer. But, we're still assuming the number input is 3.

Finally, let's have a look at `n`:

```
function repeatStr(n, s) {
    let result = "";
    while (n > 0) {
        n = n - 1;
        result = result + s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Okay, here we take both inputs `n` and `s` into consideration and we solve the problem by appending `s` exactly the number `n` times needed. This is a while loop solution, not a recursion solution. Our while loop has the action `result = result + s;` repeated exactly `n` times where we use `n` as a countdown and stop when we reach 0.

Now, we have all that background, let's look at one version of the recursion solution.

```
 function repeatStr(n, s) {
     if (n <= 0) {
         return "";
     }
     return s + repeat(n - 1, s);
 }
```

Even in recursion form we retain the countdown feature. This time the countdown is used to drive the recursion instead of a while loop. We still counting down to 0 where we have an if-return guard condition that's needed to terminate the recursion. i.e. when `n <= 0`, we exit with the simple empty string `""`. Then for the more complex case, it is solving any nth version by expressing in terms of the `(n-1)` th version. Another way of looking at it is this:

```
 repeatStr(3, "Hi") === "Hi" + repeatStr(2, "Hi")
                    === "Hi" + "Hi" + repeatStr(1, "Hi")
                    === "Hi" + "Hi" + "Hi" + repeatStr(0, "Hi")
                    === "Hi" + "Hi" + "Hi" + ""
```

If you want to get a little clever, JavaScript has a conditional which can be used in place of your if statement:

```
 function repeatStr(n, s) {
     return (n <= 0) ? "" : s + repeat(n - 1, s);
 }
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: A very nice pedagogical approach!  I personally would love to see one more step that turns this into a single-expression arrow function.

Comment: Answers like this are the best argument for the very existence of StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a decomposed approach to the other nice answers in this thread -

```js
const concat = a => b =>
  a.concat(b)

const repeat = n => f =>
  x => n && repeat(n - 1)(f)(f(x)) || x
  
const hello =
  repeat(3)(concat("Hi"))
  
console.log(hello("Alice"))
console.log(hello(""))
```

```js
HiHiHiAlice
HiHiHi
```

Comment: Nice.  I always struggle with the correct approach to curried versions of non-commutative operators like `concat`.  In a non-curried form `concat (a, b)` certainly seems as though it should return `a` followed by `b`.  But the curried form, `concat (a)` sounds like a function that given `b` should return `b` followed by `a`.  It's even worse with `subtract`: `subtract (7)` definitely sounds like a function that will take an argument and subtract `7` from it.  But `subtract (7, 4)` should return `3`.  I've thought about this for years, and never found a completely satisfactory answer.

Comment: It depends if your brain reads `subtract(7,4)` as _"from 7 subtract 4"_ or _"subtract 7 from 4"_. I don't think either is "right" but I consistency needs to be present across the library, and ideally the system. For curried functions I agree with you, it seems more natural that the order of parameters would be flipped. I share that dissatisfaction with you 100%.

Comment: This is where I get Haskell envy.  Left and right sections solve this admirably.